# Is it possible to get (near) realtime performances from CIFilter on iOS?

Tags: ios, performance, core-image

I'm trying to apply some `CIFilters` to a sequence of `CIImage` and would like to display them in realtime (at least 20-30 fps).

The images are drawn on a `GLKView` through a EAGL backed `CIContext`

When I draw my images with this code (in the update method) I get ± 20 fps (which is already a bit tight):

```
image = [image imageByApplyingTransform: CGAffineTransformMakeScale(@scale, @scale)];
[self.capture_controller.core_image_context drawImage:image atPoint: [0, 0] fromRect: image.extent];
```

If I add just one simple filter before it drops to 10-12 fps (`compo` is a `CISourceOverCompositing` filter for which the inputImage is set once for all):

```
[self.compo setValue:image forKey: @"inputBackgroundImage"];
image = [self.compo outputImage];
```

Is there any way to get better performances from CoreImage? I think UIImageView can display a sequence faster so it should be possible.

Comment: I suppose the answer is depends. Depends on what device, the resolution, and the filters and number of filters.

Comment: Yes, that's part of the issue but currently my images are fairly small (640x426).
From what I can see in the WWDC sessions video, they get realtime or almost realtime processing with simple filters on a video stream. Here I have a few images and it's slow as hell.

Comment: I'm testing on an iPhone 4 but even the simulator gives awful performances. The WWDC demo is on an iPad 2 it seems.

Comment: Well the performance in the simulator has no real bearing on performance on the device - some things are faster some things are slower. Don't expect nearly the same performance on an iPhone 4 as the iPad 2. The GPU on the iPad 2 is 9 fold faster - that is a huge difference.

Comment: Yes that's what I understand... I guess we'll have to target the lucky owners of iPhone 4S.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, from what I gathered and from Jeshua comments, performances are (obviously) bound the device and there's not much to do about it if I use CIFilters.

Comment: As a suggestion, you may want to try my new GPUImage framework: http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2012/02/12/introducing-gpuimage-framework . I'm in the process of running benchmarks on it, but in my early testing it's able to filter 640x480 frames of video through two filters in a chain at a total render time of 6 ms (~170 FPS) on an iPhone 4. What specific filter would you like to do? I could test out the timing on that particular filter chain and see if it holds up as well on the "older" hardware.

Comment: That's what we went to. I've contributed the (basic) movie input class :)

Answer (score 2):

See the WWDC 2012 videos on CoreImage for information on how to get performance.  By default the performance is limited by factors like color management.  To get best performance turn off color management when you create the CIContext, create the context only once, and create the filters only once.

Answer (score 2):

Apple is providing a manual to do this.

- [Creating a Core Image Context on iOS When You Need Real-Time Performance](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_tasks/ci_tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185-CH3-SW19)

Cited from the manual:

```
EAGLContext *myEAGLContext = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];

NSDictionary *options = @{ kCIContextWorkingColorSpace : [NSNull null] };
CIContext *myContext = [CIContext contextWithEAGLContext:myEAGLContext options:options];
```